# lilypond - hide tuplet numbers

Tags: lilypond, tuplet

I am working on translating BWV 772 into a lilypond file. I want to make it match the manuscript as much as possible. In the first bar, Bach writes the `3`s for the triplets in both voices and then you can see where the triplets are but the numbers are gone, which I think is kind of common, right?

[image: BWV 772, first bars]

In blue you can see the tuplet number, in the red squares (and in all the other triplets), the number is gone.

I have found that I can hide the brackets like this:

```
\override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = ##f
```

But how can I hide the number of the tuplet? Didn't find anything straight-forward in `TupletNumber`: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/tupletnumber

I am using lilypond 2.22.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get rid of *anything* in Lilypond, two commands can make themselves useful: `\hide` and `\omit`. Both of them get a parameter telling what should be got rid of — in this case, a `TupletNumber`. So you could use either `\hide TupletNumber` or `\omit TupletNumber`.

The difference between the two is easily seen from the names of the commands: `\hide` *hides* stuff, i. e. the hidden things still take up space but are invisible. On the other hand, `\omit` *omits* stuff, i. e. the omitted things are never put into the score in the first place and they don't take up any space. So `\omit TupletNumber` would be probably slightly more fitting.

(By the way, both of those commands can be done only `\once`. So `\once\omit TupletNumber` hides only the next `TupletNumber` encountered in the score. And they can be undone with `\undo` (e. g. `\undo\omit TupletNumber`), should you decide that you will need those numbers back later.)

Comment: This is a textbook great answer; one that doesn't just answer the question, but *teaches* the reader how to approach it both in this situation and in others. Bravo/a!